# Filtering with Integer field in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

Is it even possible to filter with Integer. I have a list where the search is working fine except one field, which is Integer. I tried to do almost the same situation in JsFiddle, but I can't even get ng-repeat working :)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <body ng-app="">
        <div ng-init="rmas = [
      {
        brand: "TIK",
        extraInfo: "lisäinfoa",
        isWarranty: false,
        litm: "T00000245",
        lotn: "00004",
        model: "A10499",
        retailer: 40001,
        retailerName: "mr Retailer",
        rmaId: 1},
      {
        brand: "SAK",
        extraInfo: "LISÄÄÄ",
        isWarranty: false,
        litm: "S2181105",
        lotn: "003500",
        model: "A30340",
        retailer: 40011,
        retailerName: "MALL SAM",
        rmaId: 2
      },
      {
        brand: "TIK",
        extraInfo: "LISÄÄÄ",
        isWarranty: false,
        litm: "T00000245",
        lotn: "00004",
        model: "A10499",
        retailer: 40000,
        retailerName: "ULF SVENSSON",
        rmaId: 3
      }
    ]"></div>
       <div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                             {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                             {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                             {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                             {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                             {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>
        
       
    
    <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
    <table id="searchTextResults">
      <tr><th>rmaId </th>  <th> retailerName </th><th> litm</th></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="rma in rmas | filter:searchText"">
        <td>{{rma.rmaId}}</td>
        <td>{{rma.retailerName}}</td>
        <td>{{rma.litm}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
        <table id="searchTextResults">
      <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
        <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
        <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <hr>
    
    </body>
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/ demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sanurmi/ry6jbgq3/2/)

Comment: Why not  put data in a a controller?

Answer (score 0):

So i corrected some of your mistake and put your data in controller, here is the [working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpmRJp)

I think your mistake is that you use " in the ng-Init just use single quote like this:

```
 <div ng-init="rmas = [
  {
    brand: 'TIK',
    extraInfo: 'lisäinfoa',
    isWarranty: false,
    litm: 'T00000245',
    lotn: '00004',
    model: 'A10499',
    retailer: '40001',
    retailerName: 'mr Retailer',
    rmaId: 1},

]"></div>
```

Comment: I just copy pasted that json from chrome devtool and that's why those ". I still wonder why in my real life app I can't filter with that rmaId. it is basically same than your demo, but json is much more complicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to implement to search fields because there is numbers in every jsons basically.  ng-model="searchKeyword.rmaId" is the way to fix that. I wonder is there any solution to filter with first with rmaID and then the rest? It would be cooler way if there is only one search field, not two. Like filter: searchKeyword.rmaId | filter: searchKeyword"

Comment: i don't understand, what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean that when user search with "any" phrase, he can't basically search with rmaID, cause there is plenty of numbers inside the jsons. If he search with number 2, the result is everything. I modified your demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dovzjY So the question is that can you get the both filters in one input field? I don't like to have to fields for that.

Comment: I see what you need now :). Hmm i think it is a bad idea to do 2 filter in 1  input because users won't understand how the filter works. Example: if users type 2 this will show "MALLSAM" but he continue to type 2 it will show "mr Retailer" and in his head he will be confused :). I think the best is to make a select option , which allows users to select by id or by name.

Comment: There is plenty of fields in my real life app, and I would like to have search from all data and rmaID. I would like to have that in one search field like so that order would be: Search FIRST from rmaID, then rest. Is this even possible without implementing this in controller in one search field?